# Why does this program give a Invalid memory access error in C?

Tags: c, string, pointers, memory, struct

```
const char *welcome(const char *language)
{
      struct options
      {
             char *language;
             char *greeting;
      };

     struct options list[17] =
     {
            {"english", "Welcome"}, {"czech","Vitejte"},
            {"danish","Velkomst"}, {"dutch","Welkom"},
            {"estonian","Tere tulemast"}, {"finnish","Tervetuloa"},
            {"flemish","Welgekomen"},{"french","Bienvenue"},
            {"german","Willkommen"},{"irish","Failte"},
            {"italian","Benvenuto"},{"latvian","Gaidits"},
            {"lithuanian","Laukiamas"},{"polish","Witamy"},
            {"spanish","Bienvenido"},{"swedish","Valkommen"},
            {"welsh","Croeso"}
     };

     for (int i = 0; i < 17; i++)
     {
         if (strcmp(language, list[i].language) == 0)
         {
            return list[i].greeting;
         }
     }  
     return "Welcome";
}
```

The program takes a string as the language, it then returns a greeting in the language, however i get an error `Test Crashed Caught unexpected signal: SIGSEGV (11). Invalid memory access`, This is the only error that appears. Why is this and how can i fix it as far as i can see everything i have done is safe.

Comment: Are you certain the error is coming from this function?  Include a simple `main` that calls this function and demonstrates the error.

Comment: Use a debugger. It will immediately tell you the exact line of code that triggers the seg fault. For further help please provide complete code as a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: You could have caused undefined behavior earlier in the program. Undefined behavior doesn't always cause an immediate crash, sometimes it corrupts memory so that later code fails.

Comment: What does the caller do with the result of this function? If it tries to modify it, you'll get a SEGV.

Comment: Most likely -- the pointer you are passing to this function is garbage (invalid pointer), so when it calls strcmp, it crashes.

Comment: FYI, silence to repeated questions about your post is a sure-fire way to get it closed, *especially* when a [mcve] request is lodged and ignored.

Comment: It's maybe because, in Irish, welcome is not "Failte" but it is "Fáilte".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with that function itself but it *may* be a problem with either:

- the way it's called; or
- what is done with the return value.

Unfortunately, both of those would be in code not included in the question, so it's supposition for now.

In the first case, if you pass something that's not a C string (such as `NULL`), you'll probably find that the `strcmp` will cause an issue.

In the second case, because you're returning a string literal, any attempt to modify it will be undefined behaviour. I would hope that fact that you're returning a pointer to `const` data would prevent that but it's hard to say without seeing the surrounding code.

---

And, just an an aside, though not really a part of the answer to your problem: while I generally applaud the use of data-driven code like your use of the options table, there are a number of problems with it.

First, the strings in the table themselves would be better off marked `const` as they are string literals that shouldn't be changed.

I see that you *return* the string as a `const` but making the items themselves `const` can sometimes give compilers more leeway to optimise code. In fact, as much as possible should be `const` unless there's a pressing reason to allow callers to change them.

---

Second, since the table never changes, you're better of using static storage duration so that the array isn't recreated every time you enter the function (a good optimiser may make that happen anyway but it's safer to force it).

---

Third, you have the magic number `17` in your code when it's not needed. That means, if you add a language, there are *three* things that need to change (the array, the size of the array, and the loop processing the array), meaning there are three things can can get out of sync and cause you problems.

---

A better approach taking all those points into consideration may be something like :

```c
const char *welcome(const char *language) {
    static const struct {
        const char *language;
        const char *greeting;
    } list[] = {
        { "czech",       "Vitejte"       },
        { "danish",      "Velkomst"      },
        { "dutch",       "Welkom"        },
        { "english",     "Welcome"       },
        { "estonian",    "Tere tulemast" },
        { "finnish",     "Tervetuloa"    },
        { "flemish",     "Welgekomen"    },
        { "french",      "Bienvenue"     },
        { "german",      "Willkommen"    },
        { "irish",       "Failte"        },
        { "italian",     "Benvenuto"     },
        { "klingon",     "nuqneH"        },
        { "latvian",     "Gaidits"       },
        { "lithuanian",  "Laukiamas"     },
        { "polish",      "Witamy"        },
        { "spanish",     "Bienvenido"    },
        { "swedish",     "Valkommen"     },
        { "welsh",       "Croeso"        }
    };

    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(list) / sizeof(*list); i++) {
        if (strcmp(language, list[i].language) == 0) {
            return list[i].greeting;
        }    
    }
    return "Welcome";
}
```

With that scheme, you can add or remove languages and no other code needs to change.

You'll see I've put `english` immediately after `dutch` (due to my CDO nature<sup>(a)</sup>) since the rest of your entries are sorted, but it *may* be you've got it at the top because (for example) it's the most likely value passed in. Feel free to change that back if there was indeed a reason for it.

The code is also formatted nicely so maintainers can easily discern what's going on.

---

*Another* possibility you may want to examine is whether it needs to be data driven at all, given it's a simple string-to-string conversion. You could equally well write well formatted code without the data-driven nature, such as:

```c
const char *welcome(const char *language) {
    if (strcmp(language, "czech"     ) == 0) return "Vitejte"       ;
    if (strcmp(language, "danish"    ) == 0) return "Velkomst"      ;
    if (strcmp(language, "dutch"     ) == 0) return "Welkom"        ;
    if (strcmp(language, "english"   ) == 0) return "Welcome"       ;
    if (strcmp(language, "estonian"  ) == 0) return "Tere tulemast" ;
    if (strcmp(language, "finnish"   ) == 0) return "Tervetuloa"    ;
    if (strcmp(language, "flemish"   ) == 0) return "Welgekomen"    ;
    if (strcmp(language, "french"    ) == 0) return "Bienvenue"     ;
    if (strcmp(language, "german"    ) == 0) return "Willkommen"    ;
    if (strcmp(language, "irish"     ) == 0) return "Failte"        ;
    if (strcmp(language, "italian"   ) == 0) return "Benvenuto"     ;
    if (strcmp(language, "klingon"   ) == 0) return "NuqneH"        ;
    if (strcmp(language, "latvian"   ) == 0) return "Gaidits"       ;
    if (strcmp(language, "lithuanian") == 0) return "Laukiamas"     ;
    if (strcmp(language, "polish"    ) == 0) return "Witamy"        ;
    if (strcmp(language, "spanish"   ) == 0) return "Bienvenido"    ;
    if (strcmp(language, "swedish"   ) == 0) return "Valkommen"     ;
    if (strcmp(language, "welsh"     ) == 0) return "Croeso"        ;
    return "Welcome";
}
```

or, if you don't like typing all that common stuff, you can use the following:

```c
const char *welcome(const char *language) {
    #define XLAT(FROM, TO) if (strcmp(language, FROM) == 0) return TO

    XLAT("czech",      "Vitejte");
    XLAT("danish",     "Velkomst");
    XLAT("dutch",      "Welkom");
    XLAT("english",    "Welcome");
    XLAT("estonian",   "Tere tulemast");
    XLAT("finnish",    "Tervetuloa");
    XLAT("flemish",    "Welgekomen");
    XLAT("french",     "Bienvenue");
    XLAT("german",     "Willkommen");
    XLAT("irish",      "Failte");
    XLAT("italian",    "Benvenuto");
    XLAT("latvian",    "Gaidits");
    XLAT("lithuanian", "Laukiamas");
    XLAT("polish",     "Witamy");
    XLAT("spanish",    "Bienvenido");
    XLAT("swedish",    "Valkommen");
    XLAT("welsh",      "Croeso");

    #undef XLAT

    return "Welcome";
}
```

Though make sure you heed the warnings about function-like macros. I rarely recommend them but they're okay in *this* situation since they're well-controlled.

When used within `if` or `while` statements without braces, for example, they can cause issues unless you cater for that explicitly (the infamous `#define X(Y) do { something with Y } while(0)` that you can no doubt find elsewhere on this site).

---

<sup>(a)</sup> OCD, but in the Correct Damn Order :-)